# Vertical alignment of navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

So, I have a navigation bar and then an `<ul>` which has some `<li>`inside. I want it to be vertically aligned with the navigation bar `.navbar` but it seems it's not working. Do anyone have andy idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is the fiddle and code: http://jsfiddle.net/x7EAg/2/

```
<style>
    .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.navbar .logo-holder {
  background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
  width: 75px;
  height: 57px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar .sections {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.navbar .sections li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>


<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo-holder"></div>
            <ul class="sections">
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by vertically aligned?

Comment: do you want the ul to appear next to the logo?

Comment: I want ul class to be in the middle of nav class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve. Then you should make the logo absolutely positioned and then aligning the `ul` can be done with `line-height`. Full css:

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  line-height:90px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.navbar .logo-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
  width: 75px;
  height: 57px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar .sections {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.navbar .sections li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
}
```

And updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gv4Lv/4/)

Comment: If you're going to position the logo absolutely you'll want to give the container element position as well.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the `display` of your `logo-holder` to `inline-block` and then set `vertical-align:middle`

now it appears next to the logo, and vertically centered.

see here for a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav5430/x7EAg/3/

this is the complete css:

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.navbar .logo-holder {
  background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
  width: 75px;
  height: 57px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.navbar .sections {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
  list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#aaa;
}
.navbar .sections li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is going on is your logo is pushing your ul down. like was mentioned above. You may want to float your logo-holder class left. That would allow you to position your li as you needed. Line-height is a way to do this, you could also use margin, padding, or absolute position for your li as needed. Good luck.